# when case switch between kernel mode and user mode for synchronized keyword in JAVA

Tags: java, mutex

When the synchronized keyword in JAVA using a mutex, if only just one thread contends for the lock, it still causes a switch between kernel mode and user mode?

The switch between kernel mode and user mode not only occurs when threads are notified or blocked, It happens whenever there's a lock contention?

Actually, i want to know how lightweight lock and bias lock improve performance for  synchronized keyword

Comment: Can you use a more comprehensible sentence structure? Also, I am sure people would like some example code for your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by kernel mode?

Comment: If he thread already holds the lock there is only a counter increment. Otherwise the lock still has to be locked.

Answer (score 2):

Let us first sort out your terminology.  If one thread is trying to acquire a mutex and the mutex is not currently held by *another* thread then there is no contention.  Contention only occurs if two or more threads are involved.

(I am also assuming that "kernel mode" means that you are switching to the privileged instruction mode used by the OS kernel and/or reloading the virtual memory context so that the CPU can access kernel data structures.  Precise details are not relevant ...)

So here are the cases:

1. No contention: a thread tries to acquire a thread when no other thread holds it.  In this case, the mutex is acquired without a switch to kernel mode.

   This includes the subcase where the thread attempts to acquire a mutex that it already holds.  That is not contention.
2. Contention: a thread tries to acquire a thread when some other thread holds it.  In this case, there are two possibilities.

   - If spinlocks are used, then the thread attempting to acquire the thread *may* poll the lock word for a period attempting to acquire it.  If that succeeds, then there is no user mode -> kernel mode switch.
   - If spinlocks are not used (or if you spin for too long), then the thread switches to kernel mode so that the current thread can be placed on hold and another thread scheduled by the OS.

Comment: according to case 1 you mentioned, how bias lock improve performance for synchronized keyword

Comment: That is a different question.  You can read about biased locking in other Q&As.  Or in this Oracle posting: https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/biased-locking-in-hotspot.  (Short version, biased locks try to avoid using CAS instructions.)